# Как правильно сделать форк ещё несмерженной ветки?

Tags: python, git, контроль-версий, workflow

Есть ветка `master`. Я сделал её форк `feature_1`, реализовал фичу и поставил `merge pull request` в `master`. Пока админ рассматривает PR, я хочу добавить ещё одну фичу, но она использует в себе код из `feature_1`. Как правильно форкаться и мержить в такой ситуации?

Ситуацию осложняет то, что после PR `feature_1`, но до PR `feature_2`, админ может принять чей-то чужой PR в `master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы изменения из `feature_1` были в `feature_2` нужно либо создавать `feature_2` напрямую от `feature_1`:

```
git checkout feautre_1
git checkout -b feature_2
```

либо создать ветку от `master` и потом слить `feature_1` в `feature_2`:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b feature_2
git merge feature_1
```

При создании PR есть два варианта:

1. PR из `feature_2` в `feature_1`
2. PR из `feature_2` в `master`

У каждого из вариантов есть плюсы и минусы описанные ниже и вам выбирать, какой лучше в вашем случае.

В первом случае более удобно делать инспекцию (code review), так как в PR видно только изменения сделанные непосредственно в `feature_2`, а изменения из `feature_1` не показываются. Минус этого варианта в том, что после того как PR из `feature_1` в `master` будет принят, нужно будет отредактировать PR из `feature_2` изменив целевую ветку на `master`.

Во втором варианте есть неудобство инспекции PR пока не будет слита ветка `feature_1`, т.к. в `feature_2` присутствуют изменения из `feature_1` и пока `feature_1` не слита в `master` эти изменения видно и в PR для `feature_2`. Но плюс в том, что не нужно делать дополнительных действий после принятия PR для `feature_1`.

Наличие других PR в `master` никак не влияет на процесс, разве что в них есть изменения конфликтующие с изменениями в `feature_1` или `feature_2`. Если это случится, то о конфликтах интерфейс github сообщит и не даст принять PR. В таком случае сначала нужно залить `master` в `feature_2` и разрешить конфликты перед тем так появится возможность принять PR.

Comment: спасибо, весьма доходчиво